# jquery найти даты ранее n-минут

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть даты

```
<span class="posted-time">[20-11-2015 04:31:57]</span>
<span class="posted-time">[20-11-2015 03:31:10]</span>
....
```

нужно найти даты, которые актуальны, если вычесть от текущей n-минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял, что имеется в виду под "актуальны". Будем считать, что нам нужны те даты, которые были раньше, чем n минут назад.

```
var nMinutesBeforeNow = new Date(Date.now() - n * 60000);

$('.posted-time').each(function() {
    var m = this.textContent.match(/^\[(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/);
    var n = m.slice(1).map(function(s) { return parseInt(s, 10); });
    var time = new Date(n[2], n[1] - 1, n[0], n[3], n[4], n[5]);
    if (time < nMinutesBeforeNow)
        console.log(time);
});
```